# Python. Вывод текста по середине терминала

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, форматирование, терминал

Как можно вывести текст в центре экрана терминала, используя `shutil.get_terminal_size().columns` и `shutil.get_terminal_size().lines`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вывести в строку и добавить пробелов в начало строки (их количество будет (ширина терминала - ширина строки) / 2 )?

Comment: @pavel Я немного поправил. Смотрите на изображение.

Comment: ну тогда могу предложить тоже самое, но отступ брать минимальный их всех строк, которые выводить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если текст уже разбит на строки, то достаточно просто отформатировать:

```
>>> import shutil
>>> lines = ['String right here', 'And here', 'Here', 'A-a-a-and here']
>>> width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
>>> position = (width - max(map(len, lines))) // 2
>>> for line in lines: # left justtified
...     print(' '*position + line)
... 
                               String right here
                               And here
                               Here
                               A-a-a-and here
>>> for line in lines: # right justified
...     print(line.rjust(width // 2))
... 
                       String right here
                                And here
                                    Here
                          A-a-a-and here
>>> for line in lines: # center
...     print(line.center(width))
... 
                               String right here                                
                                    And here                                    
                                      Here                                      
                                 A-a-a-and here
```

Comment: А как можно центрировать текст (третий пример) с выравниваем по левому краю?

Comment: Первый пример выравнивает по левому краю

Comment: Нет, чтобы он был ровно по центру экрана, как на изображении.

Comment: в чём по вашему отличие от изображения в вопросе? Куда текст подвинуть: лево, право, верх, низ?

Comment: сделал так: `nl = (height - max(map(len, textArray))) // 2 + 11;print('\n'*nl)` Всё работает.

Comment: вы можете [опубликовать ваше решение в виде ответа—это явно поощрается](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Хотя это неправильное решение, если ваше намерение было отцентрировать по высоте в терминале (код работает только, если курсор на самой верхней строчке находится). [Для произвольного позиционирования по вертикали, вне зависимости от текущего положения курсора, можно мой другой ответ использовать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518749/23044).

Comment: Нет, нужно без использования сторонних библиотек.

Comment: дополнительные ограничения следует в вопросе упоминать. Если `blessings` нельзя использовать, можно `curses` напрямую использовать. Посмотрите [пример в документации](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/)

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется в произвольном месте экрана в терминале печатать, то [можно `blessings` модуль использовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from blessings import Terminal  # $ pip install blessings

lines = ['String right here', 'And here', 'Here', 'A-a-a-and here']
term = Terminal()
with term.hidden_cursor(), term.fullscreen():
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        x = (term.width - max(map(len, lines))) // 2
        y = (term.height - len(lines)) // 2 + i
        with term.location(x, y):
            print(term.bold_white_on_black(line))

    with term.location(0, term.height - 1):
        input('press <Enter> to exit..')
```

Терминал выглядит так:

```
                               String right here
                               And here
                               Here
                               A-a-a-and here









press <Enter> to exit..
```

В этом случае, содержимое терминала на время исполнения программы очищается—при выходе из программы терминал восстанавливается.

Совместно с [`colorama` модулем](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama/), некоторые возможности могут работать также и на Windows.

---

Для забавы можно [`asciimatics` модуль](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) попробовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from asciimatics.effects import Print  # $ pip install asciimatics
from asciimatics.renderers import FigletText, SpeechBubble, Rainbow
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError


def demo(screen):
    lines = ['String right here', 'And here', 'Here', 'A-a-a-and here']
    renderers = [Rainbow(screen, FigletText(line, font='small'))
                 for line in lines]
    x = (screen.width - max(r.max_width for r in renderers)) // 2
    H = max(r.max_height for r in renderers) - 1  # text height
    effects = [Print(screen, renderer,
                     y=(screen.height - H * len(renderers)) // 2 + i * H, x=x)
               for i, renderer in enumerate(renderers)]
    effects.append(Print(screen,
                         SpeechBubble("Press X to exit"),
                         screen.height - 5,
                         speed=1, transparent=False,
                         start_frame=100))
    screen.play([Scene(effects, -1)], stop_on_resize=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            Screen.wrapper(demo)
        except ResizeScreenError:
            continue
        else:
            break
```

[image: print-asciimatics tty session]

На другие доступные эффекты можно в [samples папке](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/tree/master/samples) посмотреть.