# с помощью чего сделать обновляемую таблицу в bash/cmd терминале на Python?

Tags: python, curses

просто вот такую простую таблицу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

главное чтоб ширина ячеек была фиксированная.

пробовал curses - какая то мудреная и недокументированная.
urwid - Тоже самое

нашел отличный модуль **terminaltables**
но он почему то не реагирует на

```
sys.stdout.write('\r%s' % table)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

и таблицу обновить не получается

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: "не реагирует на" `\r` Что вы хотели добиться с помощью `\r`? Достаточно ли в вашем случае очистить экран и напечатать таблицу с новыми данными?

Comment: достаточно. но по моему это как то не правильно. Таблица же будет обновлятся ооооочень быстро. И  к тому же возможно будет моргать, это мне не надо

Comment: @JohnDoe напишите код, если будет моргать, тогда спросите как сделать так чтобы не моргало. Чтобы напечатать таблицу: [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/4279). Чтобы очистить экран [Python - Clearing the terminal screen more elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Пример таблицы чисел, которые 10 раз в секунду обновляются пока <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> не нажать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
import time

def main():
    interval = 1 / 10
    while True:
        # update table
        table = [[random.randrange(10) for _ in range(6)] for _ in range(3)]
        # clear screen
        print('\033c')
        # print table
        for row in table:
            print(*row)
        time.sleep(interval - time.monotonic() % interval)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Существует несколько библиотек, которые позволяют напечатать в консоль двухмерные данные [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9535954/4279).

Более переносимым способом очистить экран в терминале, может быть [`curses.tigetstr('clear')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34388390/4279), [`blessings.Terminal.clear`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279) и/или [`colorama.ansi.clear_screen()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108770/4279).

Необязательно весь экран перерисовывать, к примеру, `blessings` не требует очищать экран, чтобы печатать в произвольном месте и [обновить только нужную часть экрана](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518749/23044). Чтобы произвольную анимацию создать, [можно использовать `asciimatics`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051472/4279).