# Вывести на экран прогресс бар, а над ним выводить лог выполнения

Tags: python

Недавно начал изучать `Python`, столкнулся с проблемой вывода данных в несколько уровней. Необходимо вывести на экран прогресс бар, а над ним выводить лог выполнения.

```
count, bar_len = 50, 20
for i in range( count ):
    #print( '{}'.format( i ) )
    d = math.floor( bar_len / count * ( i + 1 ) )
    text = '\r|{0}{1}|'.format( '#' * d, '-' * ( bar_len - d ) )
    #print( text, end = '' )
    sys.stdout.write( text )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep( 1 )
```

```
|#########-----------|
```

Если запустить код, прогресс бар работает, но если убрать верхний комментарий с `print`, получается каша:

```
0
|--------------------|1
|--------------------|2
|#-------------------|3
|#-------------------|4
```

Как заставить их подружиться? Что бы сверху выводилась информация с новой строки, а с низу обновлялся прогресс бар и на выходе получалось следующие:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5

|##------------------|
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Python. Вывод текста по середине терминала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518707/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [с помощью чего сделать обновляемую таблицу в bash/cmd терминале на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/715269/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вывести индикатор выполнения под журнальными сообщениями, [можно использовать `tqdm` модуль](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#writing-messages) (читается как [«такадум»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdoZvo8j6tc) — означает «прогресс»):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import tqdm  # $ pip install tqdm

progress_bar = tqdm.trange(10)
for i in progress_bar:
    time.sleep(.1)
    progress_bar.write("loop %i" % i)
```

[image: progress bar under log messages]

Answer (score 0):

Если не сверху, а сбоку, то вот так

```
import math
import sys
import time
count, bar_len = 50, 20
for i in range( count ):
    #print( '{}'.format( i ), end=" " )
    d = math.floor( bar_len / count * ( i + 1 ) )
    text = '\r|{0}{1}|'.format( '#' * d, '-' * ( bar_len - d ) )
    print( text, i, end = '' )
    sys.stdout.write( text )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep( 1 )
```