# Модуль python для работы с консолью (windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, командная-строка

Хочу написать текстовую игру в консоли, типа мини RPG, в плане:
Перед вам 2 двери, в какую хотите войти и т.д.
А так же реализовать битвы с врагами.
В С# есть такой класс `Console`, с множеством полезных методов, а именно:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition()
Console.CursorLeft
Console.CursorTop
```

И так же методы для изменения цвета текста и фона.
Мне надо подобный модуль на Python, потому что `os.system()` не хватает.
Если такого модуля нет для python, посоветуйте пожалуйста язык программирования для этой цели, а то C# слишком сложен для такой простой цели.

Comment: Модуля нет, но есть множество библиотек. Например, BearLibTerminal или UniCurses.

Comment: посмотрите подойдёт ли для вас blessings + colorama.

Comment: [примеры кода для blessings и asciimatics](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/518749/23044)